# Need help creating battery alert using visual basic

Tags: vbscript

**Hi**,

I have been searching for resources, programs and code that will **create an alert for me to unplug my charger when my laptop battery is charged to full (or almost full).**

I **haven't had any success** until I came across this blog - http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2013/04/24/get-an-alert-when-my-battery-reaches-95.aspx

The only **problem** with this code is that

> Line 13: iRemaining (or RemainingCapacity called from BatteryStatus returns a 0 (might be a floating point which I can't figure out why). I even checked the microsoft documentation and its supposed to be a percentage.

I want to get either the current percentage of the battery or the total Fullchargedcapacity and the EstimatedRemainingCapacity to find the % of battery level.

**Essentially what I am asking is how can I return the battery % using visual basic script.**

Help!

**The Code**:

```
 1 set oLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
 2 set oServices = oLocator.ConnectServer(".","root\wmi")
 3 set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batteryfullchargedcapacity")
 4 for each oResult in oResults iFull = oResult.FullChargedCapacity
 5 next
 6 
 7  while (1)
 8     set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batterystatus")
 9     for each oResult in oResults
 10      iRemaining = oResult.RemainingCapacity
 12      bCharging = oResult.Charging
 12 next
 13 iPercent = ((iRemaining / iFull) * 100) mod 100
 14 if bCharging and (iPercent > 95) Then msgbox "Battery is at " & iPercent "%",vbInformation,"Battery monitor"
 15 wscript.sleep 30000 ' (30 seconds)
 16 wend
```

Comment: Just to let you know there is a method to do it without coding . You can do it by following the steps here:http://www.7tutorials.com/set-windows-play-alarm-sounds-when-reaching-low-or-critical-battery

Comment: VBA, basic, and Visual Basic are three separate languages, and are not compatible. There is also VB.Net, which is also separate and not compatible. Visual C++ is not related in any way, shape or form (other than being a Microsoft product). What **specific language** are you asking about here? Don't just randomly grab tags - add the ones that actually apply to your question.

Comment: @ Ken White - All there was when choosing tags was Visual. I didn't know it was going to resolve to VBA. Also your answer was not helpful in any way. @Mohit I'm looking for FULL battery not low or critical.

Comment: Your script "hangs" because you have no condition set in your `While` statement to tell the code when to exit the loop. Therefore  your script is looping infinitely and consuming CPU

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the major issue is that you have no way to tell if your code is doing what you want.  If it is running successfully, it will use some CPU (although it shouldn't be much), and not show you anything until your battery is charged.  For debuggig, try changing

```
if bCharging and (iPercent > 95) Then msgbox "Battery is at " & iPercent & "%",vbInformation, "Battery monitor"
```

to

```
msgbox "Battery is at " & iPercent & "%",vbInformation, "Battery monitor"
```

This will let you see your results, and get an idea of if your code is working.

**BTW**

`wscript.sleep` takes time in milliseconds.  So, your call of `wscript.sleep 30000` will only wait for 30 seconds, not 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So the error message popped up and it basically means a divide by 0 error. So I'm not sure if RemainingCapacity is returning an actual value.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not meant to be a percentage.

This line `iPercent = ((iRemaining / iFull) * 100) mod 100` changes it to a percentage.

The documentation you were referring to is likely for powershell, the script you are using is vbs.

One reason you are seeing 0 is perhaps you have 2 batteries, and the code is just pulling the second drained battery. If so, this should work>

```
set oLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
set oServices = oLocator.ConnectServer(".","root\wmi")
set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batteryfullchargedcapacity")
 
for each oResult in oResults
    iFull = oResult.FullChargedCapacity
next

bCharging = True
while (1 and bCharging)
    set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batterystatus")
    totalRemaining = 0
    batteryCount = 0
    for each oResult in oResults
        iRemaining = oResult.RemainingCapacity
        bCharging = oResult.Charging
        totalRemaining = totalRemaining + iRemaining
        batteryCount = batteryCount + 1
    next
    iPercent = Round(((totalRemaining / batteryCount) / iFull) * 100)
    
    if bCharging and (iPercent > 95) Then msgbox "Battery is at " & iPercent & "%",vbInformation, "Battery monitor"
    wscript.sleep 3000000 ' sleep for 5 minutes
wend
```